# How to scale and then trim an image?

Tags: adjustbox, scale, clip

I am trying to create a document that requires the inclusion of images at a precise size (h x w inches). I would like to reuse the document template, so I would like to create a command that would resize and clip any image (sized H x W inches) to the right size (h x w in), provided that the full width (W) is **first scaled down** to the new width (w), and then the new H is **trimmed** to the height h. How do I do this in LaTeX?

```
+---------------------+---+
|       w             |   |
|                     |   |
|                     |   |
|h                    |   |
|                     |   |
|                     |  H|
|                     |   |
+---------------------+   |
|                         |
|                         |
|             W           |
+-------------------------+
```

[EDIT]

Reading some posts here, I have tried to solve this using the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength{\oH}
\newlength{\nH}

\newcommand{\PrintImage}[3]{%
% #1 : desired width
% #2 : desired height
% #3 : image
\settoheight{\oH}{\includegraphics{#3}}
\settoheight{\nH}{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#3}}

\adjincludegraphics[width=#1,trim={0 {\oH - #2} 0 0},clip=true]{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering

\PrintImage{2in}{2in}{myimage}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work. Thinking that the problem was that I was using the original height **oH**, I changed the `\adjincludegraphics` line to:

```
\adjincludegraphics[width=#1,trim={0 {\nH - #2} 0 0},clip=true]{#3}%
```

But it doesn't work either. Why?

Comment: I assume you actually want something that is even *more* general: scale down (only if needed) so that *either* height or width needs to be trimmed to fit within the h:w proportions.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. So any image could be used without the hassle of scaling it and trimming it by hand.

Comment: \includegraphic[width=W in]{figure1} would be sufficient then isn't it?

Comment: @RickdeGroot: That wouldn't give the right height.

Comment: @Amaru: You need to give more information. Should the images be trimmed on top or on both sides? Do you really mean trimming or actually clipping, i.e. should the trimmed part still be visible or not?

Comment: Because the image would be **scaled** from **W** to **w**, it would need to be **trimmed** from **H** to **h** (and the trimmed part should not be visible).

Comment: Note that with recent `adjustbox` the original height of the content (here the image) is accessible as `\Height` for use in the `adjustbox` keys. There is also `\Width` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the generic `ClipImage` command, based on **PolGab** answer:

```
\documentclass[11pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newlength{\oH}
\newlength{\oW}
\newlength{\rH}
\newlength{\rW}
\newlength{\cH}
\newlength{\cW}
\newcommand\ClipImage[3]{% width, height, image
\settototalheight{\oH}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
\settowidth{\oW}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
\setlength{\rH}{\oH * \ratio{#1}{\oW}}%
\setlength{\rW}{\oW * \ratio{#2}{\oH}}%
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\rH < #2}}{%
    \setlength{\cW}{(\rW-#1)*\ratio{\oH}{#2}}%
    \adjincludegraphics[height=#2,clip,trim=0 0 \cW{} 0]{#3}%
}{%
    \setlength{\cH}{(\rH-#2)*\ratio{\oW}{#1}}%
    \adjincludegraphics[width=#1,clip,trim=0 \cH{} 0 0]{#3}%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering

\ClipImage{0.5in}{3in}{myimage}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much again.

Comment: As Martin Sharrer said in its comment, your `ClipImage` command is not completely generic. Why do you clip right or bottom side and not left or top side ? Why do you not center the image before clipping two opposite sides ?

Comment: I stand corrected. It is not completely generic, but for my project this is what I need. The images I will be using include the most relevant information lined up to the upper left corner. I can see, thought, that a generic solution could be tailored from this command. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Here a `\PrintImage` macro that clips the bottom of the included image if its height is too large.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newlength{\oH}
\newlength{\oW}
\newlength{\rH}
\newlength{\cH}
\newcommand\PrintImage[3]{% width, height, image
  \settototalheight{\oH}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
  \settowidth{\oW}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
  \setlength{\rH}{\oH * \ratio{#1}{\oW}}
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\rH < #2}}{
    \includegraphics[width=#1]{#3}%
  }{%
    \setlength{\cH}{(\rH-#2)*\ratio{\oW}{#1}}%
    \includegraphics[width=#1,clip,trim=0 \cH{} 0 0]{#3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I very new to LaTeX, and I was struggling with this issue. I have changed `includegraphics` for `adjincludegraphics`, because the former didn't seem to work. This requires loading `adjustbox` too. With some small changes, based on your excellent solution, I have created a generic `ClipImage` command that will fit an image to a given size, clipping the side that overflows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Clip` key of `\adjincludegraphics` together with the `\height` macro which is set to the current height of the adjusted content. Note that `Clip` works differently as `trim` with `clip` because it is executed in a different order (as the later two come from `graphics`).

```
\documentclass[11pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}



\newcommand{\PrintImage}[3]{%
% #1 : desired width
% #2 : desired height
% #3 : image
    \adjustimage{width={#1},Clip=0 {\height-#2} 0 0}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\hspace{2in}\rule{2in}{2in}

\rule{2in}{2in}\PrintImage{2in}{2in}{example-image-a4}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

The black bars are for size reference.