# Producing "glossy" documents

Tags: pdftex, tex-general

Without going into too much extraneous detail, currently our product manual is produced using some proprietary WYSIWYG editor, which has a bunch of limitations. I'm considering producing the manual using `pdfLaTeX` instead. The *main* motivation for this is so we can put the copy in source control. (You can't do that when your document is just a binary blob.)

Doing this is going to require a whole heap of work, so before I even start this I have to ask: Is LaTeX the correct tool for the job? Or would I be better off some other document technology? (E.g., DocBook ⇒ XSLT ⇒ XML-FO ⇒ PDF or something.)

We want our product manual to look like a trendy article in a glossy magazine, and our graphics department have done an excellent job of achieving that look. Obviously management won't accept anything that looks worse than what we already have.

LaTeX is of course *excellent* at producing really professional-looking academic publications. But to our target audience, that just looks "scary". We don't want customers thinking you need a PhD to understand our software. Hence the current manual has huge sans-serif fonts, liberal splashes of colour, and varying page layouts to make it not look like a "wall of text". And, being a software manual, it has *a lot* of screenshots (frequently featuring complicated call-outs with arrows).

I have no doubt that if you put enough experts in a room and hit it hard enough, you can probably make TeX render just about *anything*. But something being *possible* isn't the same as being *easy*. And saying that TeX *can* do something isn't the same as saying it's the *best* tool for the job &mdash or even the *right* tool for the job.

So what do we think, folks? Is TeX a good tool for this, or is there something else out there that's likely to be a better fit?

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question, as we have not seen an example how it should like. But I dare say, that LaTeX should perhaps not be the first choice for a `glossy magazine`, although there have been a lot of enhancements in the past.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If the question was "how do I make LaTeX render this exact page?" it would presumably be closed as too specific. But perhaps a rough example would be beneficial. I'll see if I can obfuscate a page of the manual...

Comment: this isn't quite the same subject matter, but at tug 2011, there was a presentation on ["Typesetting fancy multilingual phrase books with LuaTeX"](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/typesetting-fancy-multilingual-phrase-books-with-luatex/); this was recorded on video, which should be accessible from the linked page.  another example, published in tugboat is ["How to make a product catalog that doesn't look like a dissertation"](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-3/tb108lewis.pdf).  maybe those will give you some ideas.

Comment: "[V]arying page layouts" might be the biggest drawback if you want to use some form of TeX: *TeX likes uniform page layouts. Changing the textblock on each page or every couple of pages will require (afaik) frequent manual intervention (e.g., special boxes here, two-column stuff there, wider margins on that page, skinny ones with a big picture on this page, etc., etc.).  I suppose it depends on your idea of what constitutes 'easy'....

Comment: @barbarabeeton The second link seems interesting. I *think* the resulting catalogue is <a href="http://organictrader.com.au/catalogue/">here</a>, and it does indeed look very glossy indeed.

Comment: @jon Looking at the latest revision of the manual, it seems the layout is a bit less complicated than I recall. The main thing that happens a lot is text around the sides of pictures. There aren't too many pages with varying numbers of columns, etc.

Comment: Hmm, how about [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54065/8528) then?  FYI: The OP there, @YiannisLazarides, has often asked and answered some interesting questions about design and layout on this site.

Comment: I suspect, though I am not sure, that there is going to be significant tension between the 2 desiderata you mention. That is, the tools which are best suited for producing documents from plain text source, which is ideal for version control, are not going to be the ones which are best suited to laying out pages in the ways you describe. That is, they are not going to be the most straightforward or intuitive tools for doing it, and they are going to require a good deal of manual intervention. They are unlikely to be tools the marketing department will like working with. (Unless you have an...

Comment: ... unusual marketing department composed of either TeX-nicians or masochists.) the kinds of layouts you describe are not very easy to define in plain text (call-outs, for example), and frequent changes of page layout are best done in light of the content of those pages, which means more mucking around when not using a GUI. That said, `flowfram` might be of interest. But note the caveats in its documentation: it gets TeX to do things TeX was not designed to do, and that depends on performing major surgery on the output routine.

Comment: [My answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199960/comic-book-or-graphic-novel-style-panels-in-latex/200040#200040) demonstrates the basic idea in an admittedly simple-minded way.

Comment: @cfr I find your comment particularly insightful since it applies not only to TeX, but to *anything* that lets us have source control...

Comment: That's my worry, yes. If you'd just asked was TeX the best option for producing these layouts, I'd simply say no. (Exception: if people are already very comfortable with TeX and like it, and not familiar with other tools, then it might make perfect sense. But I guess your marketing department doesn't fit that description.) But I don't know if you'll find a *better* tool, given that you *also* want source control. There are going to be serious trade-offs here...

Comment: I believe [tag:ConTeXt] may be the better choice here: AFAIK it's better tailored at designers. See [Why should I be interested in ConTeXt?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4987)

Answer (score 3):

To the extent that my slightly vague question admits an "answer"...

I spent the last several days trying to recreate the existing document using LaTeX. This has been broadly successful. As a result of many hours of study, I have discovered:

- There exists something called XeTeX, which allows me to use the same expensive commercial font that the existing document has. (Sadly this also makes everything take 200x longer to compile, but hey...)
- I find something called `tikz` which allows me to draw fancy multi-coloured borders, rounded corners, callouts, etc. with comparative ease.
- Using the `geometry` package, I was able to reduce the generous LaTeX page margins to the meager slithers that glossy documents seem to have.
- Using `fancyhdr` I managed to edit the page headers and footers to look like how I want (rather than the LaTeX defaults). I also managed to colour in the outside page margins. (I was particularly worried about TeX being unable to do that, but again TikZ managed to fix it.)
- Using `tocloft` I was able to match the table of contents in the original document. (In particular, setting chapter titles in a different colour to everything else to make them stand out.)
- Using `titlesec` I was able to replace the very academic-looking chapter headings with something much more glossy-looking.
- I had to resort to manually tweaking TeX lengths to get paragraphs with vertical spaces rather than horizontal indents. But it wasn't too hard.

So far, the resulting (unfinished) document looks pretty damned similar to the original. *However*, I haven't yet tried inserting any screenshots, nor labelling them up. Inserting a picture shouldn't be a problem, but drawing arrows to the correct parts might be fun. However, knowing now that TikZ exists, it *should* be just a case of figuring out the correct coordinates (which only needs to be done once). In short, I'm fairly confident it can be done, and can be fairly containable. (Then again, I haven't actually *done* it yet, so...)

In summary: Yeah, you can definitely make something kinda shiny with LaTeX. Maybe not as immaculate as what our graphics department could produce, but pretty damned good. (And without needing to micro-manage page-breaks, manually keep fonts / margins / page titles consistent, and so forth.)

---

**Edit**:

Some people wanted to see the actual document. Unfortunately I have to obscure all the text, which makes it a bit difficult to tell what the thing actually looks like! But here is a heavily blurred image of the opening chapter of the manual:

[image: Original manual]

And here is what my new version looks like:

[image: New manual]

It looks a bit ugly because the Lorem Ipsum paragraphs are all *so long!* But with the actual document text, it looks pretty similar, actually. And when I get access to the actual commercial font on my work PC, it should look pretty much identical.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot of the original and your recreation?

Comment: @Argo Yeah, I'll see if I can arrange that...

Comment: You may be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/17423 for figuring out the right coords.  If you have an image-analysis toolchain, you could even come up with the coordinates dynamically.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yeah. Well, I guess I could just ask our application what coordinates it's drawn the widgets at. In fact, come to think of it... I can query that with AT-SPI. Maybe I can automate the entire screen-shot capture / coordinate capture process... Hmm.

Comment: You've learned a lot of TeX in a short time - I'm impressed. If your success means you move your product manual to TeX you might be the only person in your shop who can work on it. That could be a problem for you and for the rest of the company.

Comment: @EthanBolker I've been using TeX for years. But I've never tried to customise its output before. The only people who will be touching the manual are computer programmers like myself; I'm sure they can learn the syntax easily enough. Customising TeX is hard; getting it to typeset prose is trivial. ;-)

Comment: @EthanBolker I should perhaps also point out that this website has been extremely useful over the past few days. Almost every random bug and glitch I came across was solved by a quick Google search, leading to somebody else who has already asked the same question here. Naturally, I up-voted all the Qs and As that helped me. ;-)