# Camera film effect to put in sequence the images

Tags: graphics, packages, draw, technical-drawing

I wished to know if there is a specific `package` to put in a sequence of images like the old films of a camera or old movies.
Just as an alternative for my book the effect of which could also be very nice.

Correctly, with sincerity, this is a "*do this for me*" question.

I have no idea if I must to create successive tables, or to do a drawing with *TikZ*/*PStricks* (using successive iterations), or with other tricks, but I'm curious how you would set up the solution.

I put some images:
[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpixabay.com%2Fit%2Fvectors%2Fnegativi-pellicola-fotografia-155925%2F&psig=AOvVaw1Bn4L2_kFBlBI8BMxxolZc&ust=1624137204025000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAcQjRxqFwoTCOCu8euMovECFQAAAAAdAAAAABAK]

[image: https://previews.123rf.com/images/frenta/frenta1610/frenta161000104/65936235-retr%C3%B2-pellicola-con-texture-carta-grunge-.jpg]

Comment: Here is a related qestion: [A movie film strip of images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167940/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Hi very kind...my question it is sincerely a duplicate. Considering the best answer, how I can put the images (it is possible to use the example images of tikz ducks, for example)? Is it possible to improved the code after 7 years? In the meantime a put my closure like a duplicate.